# Bound Settings works in Visual Designer but I can't run the app

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, binding, exception

I am using Visual C# Studio 2010 Express and I have oakward problem. I wanted to bind few TextBoxes to application Settings. I've followed Paul Sheriff's solution [Paul Sheriff's solution](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/10/19/binding-to-config-settings-in-wpf.aspx). It works only in visual designer - I can't run the app, cause i got:

> XmlParseException 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.

How is it possible, that it's working in visual designer (values are presented in TextBoxes correctly) but there is a XmlParseException?

App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="odpSettings" ObjectType="{x:Type setts:Settings}" />
</Application.Resources>`
```

The setts namespace is defined as `xmlns:setts="clr-namespace:DbCopier.Properties"`

My view:

```
<TextBox
    Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource odpSettings}, Path=Default.DbName}"
    Width="150" />
```

Comment: This is nice one ;) And the InnerException is: `{"Cannot find resource named 'odpSettings'. Resource names are case sensitive."}`. Unfortunately all names are correct (if they wouldn't - why proper values are visible in visual designer?).

Comment: Never base any argument on the designer, for it is utter crap. But this is odd indeed...

Comment: It's true, that Paul Sheriff used this way to bound to his own class with some settings but I think it should work with default Settings file. I guess it's not.

Comment: You can bind to the default settings without creating an instance as they are static. Just use `x:Static`. `{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, Path=DbName}`

Comment: @H.B. - yes, it also works, but still - Properties in Settings object has to be under `User` scope. If not - similar, confusing exception will occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

The InnerException was pretty damn confusing. It's all about the Property Scope in Settings file. I've noticed it was changed to `Application`, so it was read-only. I just changed it to `User` so it became writable. So easy and yet - so annoying mistake.